# JPA Synchronize issues, need to restart application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I've made an application where all my databases querys are done with JPA. I have an method where I edit one column, code added below;

```
public static void setReservationAsUnactive(Reservation obj) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    obj.setActive(0);
    obj.setReturnedDate(new Date());
    em.merge(obj);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

I can see that the column is changed correctly in my mysql database, but when I'll try to pull it out in a JPA query the changes are not there, however - when i restart the application, the changes are made... How can I ensure the data that I pull out, is fresh data and not some cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for feedback. But I solved it by getting the object from were I originally retrieved it from.

Example:

```
// this will work, and it will update the database, but the user need to restart his client to view the edited row
public void btnSetReservationToUnactive() {
    TableObject tableObject = getSelectedObject();
    ReservationBean.setReservationAsUnactive(ReservationBean.getReservationByID(tableObject.getID()));

}

// this method will update the current clients view also, because it get the object were it originally came from.
// rather than getting a new object from the em.
public void btnSetReservationToUnactive() {
    TableObject tableObject = getSelectedObject();
    ReservationBean.setReservationAsUnactive(getReservationByIdFromTable(tableObject.getID()));

}

public Reservation getReservationByIdFromTable(int resID) {
    for (Reservation res : customer.getReservationCollection()){
        if (res.getID() == resID)
            return res;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to evict your object  from the cache

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(theClass, thePrimaryKey);
```

Other solution is delete the cache storage(Bad solution for me). [Guide for disabling the cache storage](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F)

And here are is the [documentation of the cache and how is stored in JPA](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to get your entity from underlying database by  `em.refresh(obj);`

Please advise if you are caching entity manager?